# Calling constant attributes of a class from laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the next class.

```
    namespace App\Repository\Constants\Models;

class InstanceModelContant
{
    const ALREADY_DEMO = "Usted ya posee un demo.";
    const ALREADY_INSTANCE = "Ya tiene un servidor con estas caracteristicas.";
    const INSTANCE_DEMO_TYPE = "t2.micro";
    const CHAR_NOT_PUBLIC_ADDRESS = "--";
}
```

within the class defined several constants that I use in several places throughout the project.

in blade I have to make a comparison of the attribute of a model that would look like this

```
@if($instancia->publicip == '--')
                        {{$instancia->publicip}}
                    @else
                    <h1>hola mundo</h1>
                    @endif
```

But as I see I have to remove the code from the - what I want is to use the **CHAR_NOT_PUBLIC_ADDRESS** attribute inside the blade and not burn the code.
Or else I could advise

Comment: You need to define constants as `public`.

Comment: friend @RazaMehdi and as I call the attributes being the class in the namespace App \ Repository \ Constants \ Models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@if($instancia->publicip == App\Repository\Constants\Models\InstanceModelContant::CHAR_NOT_PUBLIC_ADDRESS)
```